# How to give corner radius to the background image where the top rounded image is attached to the background image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-xml-attribute

How to give corner radius to the background cover picture, where the upper rounded picture is attached with this. Can anyone help me to get this design? Like this image ...[Expecting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0XE2.jpg), But right now I am just capable to get this [Getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl4NF.jpg).

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@color/bgColor"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coverImg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/coverImg"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainRoundImage"
                android:src="@drawable/roundImg"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/borderColor"
                app:civ_border_width="8dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Links are not attached.

Comment: @Khemraj Sorry fo that, I am new here. Now I updated my question